# Angular 2 Routing - Cannot match any routes in URL Segment

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have lost over 7 days with this, but couldn't get it to work. When I put path to the template in the `children`, I get the error, and application crashes.

Here is my code:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'store', component: StoreComponent, 
    children: [
          {path: 'apple', component: AppleComponent}
    ]
}
```

AppleComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Type} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component ({
    selector: 'apple',
    templareUrl: '../apple.html
})

export class AppleComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(){}

     nGOnInit():void{}
}
```

I have put the `<base href="/">` in the index.html file but that didn't help.

I have just started learning Angular2, so please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question.

EDIT: This would need to go in the `children` because of `router-outlet`.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this

```
{ path: 'store/apple', component: AppleComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Alternatively you can use this way,

```
export const storeChildrenRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'store',
    component: StoreComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'apple',
        component: AppleComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(storeChildrenRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class StoreChildRoutingModule {}
```

Have this as a separate module and import this to the AppRouting module.
where you AppRouting module will contain your main routes which has

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRootRoutes)
```

Comment: Yes I can, but I need it in the children, because of router-outlet.

Comment: are you using <router-outlet> inside your `StoreComponent`

Comment: No, how would you do that exactly?

Comment: my question is then why you want it to be a children route of it?

Comment: Because it is the part of the wrapper. How would you put router-outlet inside?

Comment: my question is why do you want to the apple component to be a child of your store component?

Comment: Because it is the sub-link of the /store/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135989/discussion-between-aravind-and-eric-dummy).